# Relationship between different tables same foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image]

I have an `Assets` table that stores the information of files uploaded to the website (images, pdfs, docs, etc.).

These files can be a photo of a News article, an avatar of a member, a pdf file of an article, etc.

I have unique `Guid` columns in all tables. In this way, I can access all files belonging to the data in any table through the `Guid` column in the `Assets` table.

For example, all assets of the news with Id 12:

```
SELECT News.Title, Assets.Filename 
FROM News 
INNER JOIN Assets ON News.Guid = Assets.Guid 
WHERE News.Id = 12
```

For example, all assets of the user whose Id is 179:

```
SELECT Users.Fullname, Assets.Filename 
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN Assets ON Users.Guid = Assets.Guid 
WHERE Users.Id = 179
```

Is it possible to do this without defining a foreign key for all tables separately?

If possible, how can I establish this relationship through Entity Framework?

Comment: I suggest a table part type inheritance model where in the primary key is used as the foreign key in the underlying database

Comment: As this question relates to EF relationships, and not just concepts, it helps to include the EF configuration and model classes

Comment: As @ChrisSchaller pointed out, more information about your configuration is required. Also specify your EF version.

Answer (score 1):

The 1:1 relationship for `Category` and `Product` with `Asset` can be established by adding an `Asset` navigation property and optionally an `AssetId` to both `Category` and `Product`.

Many to Many relationships like what you have described for News are better modelled with an interim table that links to two. The practical reason for defining the linking table in EF, instead of at the DB level only as a shadow table, is that you will likely have other metadata about the *Asset* and how it relates to the article, usually sorting, indexing and other layout information.

> I would not include the inverse navigation property to go from `Asset` back to any of these linked tables, in EF the schema change management tools like *migrations* just make a mess of shadow linking tables over time.

So this means add a `NewsAsset` entity that has a `N : 1` with `News` and a `1 : 1` with `Asset`.